# What pattern should I use in Akka, now that Transactors are deprecated?

Tags: akka

Since Transactors [have been deprecated](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html), which pattern should I use instead? I have the need to synchronize between different actors. I have some (dynamic) dependencies, where Actor B must not start work before Actor A has finished.

Comment: Is it possible to coordinate the work by sending messages between the actors?

Comment: Not between individual actors, since they don't know of each other, but I have a solution now that involves a managing queue actor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a good solution for my specific problem. Namely, we will now use a dedicated actor that manages a queue, and each worker actor will send a message that it likes to start its work. This wish is put into the queue, and the queue actor will send out a "Go ahead" message when the queue is sufficiently advanced.

However I'd still like to know if there is a more general concept that will replace Transactors in coming Akka releases.